# PowerPC 970 Based Macs, Why Is Hypervisor Mode Unavailable?

Tags: virtualization, powerpc

I recently have acquired a Apple G5 computer (PPC 970) and am interested in learning more about the PowerPC architecture (most of my systems programming knowledge comes from x86 and my own hobby kernel).

After using the computer a while and getting used to PowerPC assembly (RISC), I noticed that low level CPU virtualization is not possible on PowerPC 970 based Macs. The CPU in documentation (PowerPC 64) seems to support hypervisor mode, but it has been noted that it is not possible due to Open Firmware.

Do all operating systems which are loaded from Open Firmware on PowerPC 970 series Macs load in hypervisor mode, making "nested" virtualization impossible? If this is true, why does Open Firmware load all Operating systems in hypervisor mode? Is this in order to provide a secure layer for communication between the the Operating System and Open Firmware (using firmware for everything except ACPI and memory discovery during boot, which requires a transition into "real-mode", is unsafe in x86?).

Also if the Operating system were using hyper-calls to facilitate a secure transition to firmware based routines, wouldn't this impose a large penalty just as syscalls do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not privy to Apple's hardware designs, but I've heard that the HV mode (ie., HV=1 in the Machine State Register) was disabled, through hardware, on the CPUs used in the G5 machines.

If this is the case, then it's not up to the system firmware to enable/disable HV mode - it's simply not available.

At the time that these machines were available, other Power hardware designs had a small amount of firmware running in HV=1 mode, and only exposed HV=0 to the kernel. However, the G5 wasn't one of these.

Comment: Do you know why the HV machine register was disabled? did the MMU and core not support hypervisor mode or was this a consciences hardware decision for some "security" reason?

Comment: I would assume that this was simply to reduce development & test costs - if the feature is disabled in hardware, there's a whole set of functionality that doesn't need to be verified.